# Get pixel from bitmap

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, bitmap, pixel

I need to process pixeldata from a 1000x1000px *.bmp image (~1MiB) in javascript
At the moment i am a bit stuck, because the page freezes when i try to dump the data to the console.
the important code so far:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'image.bmp';
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
console.log(context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width));
```

i guess this is a performance issue, but is there a better way to access the pixel data? i dont really need to read it all at once, reading the pixels one by one would also be fine.

EDIT:

here is the updated code, it will populate a 2d-array with the red-value of the picture (i am dealing with a black/white picture, so thats enough)

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'image.bmp';
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
var imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
var pixel = new Array();
for(i=0;i<canvas.height;i++){
    pixel[i] = new Array();
    for(j=0;j<canvas.width;j++){
        pixel[i][j] = imgData.data[i*canvas.width+j*4];
    }
}
//now pixel[y][x] contains the red-value of the pixel at xy in img
```

no performance issues :) only quirk is that rows/columns are reversed

Comment: Silly Question: Have you tried to do it with a small image first to make it work?

Comment: You are dumping *1 million pixels* to the console and wondering why the browser freezes? Seriously?

Comment: Pekka: yeah, i figured that it was a performance issue, if i knew a way to access the pixels one by one, i would not have asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var data   = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
var count  = 0;
var tmr    = null;
var length = data.length; 
(pix = function() { 
    var r = data[count + 0];
    var g = data[count + 1];
    var b = data[count + 2];
    var a = data[count + 3];
    var rgba = 'rgba('  + r + ' ,' + g + ' ,' + b +   ' ,' + a + ')'; 
    console.log(rgba); 
    if((count += 4) >= length) { 
        clearTimeout(tmr);
        return;
    }
    tmr = setTimeout(pix, 1000/30); //at 30 fps
})();
```

Comment: i have some questions: in the $-1 line, shouldnt it be s/clr/tmr/ ? and what is this (x=function(){})();-structure called, so i can learn some more about it (google is not so good with parens/braces). I wont mark it as answer yet, because even with 300fps this takes almost 1h. i have to test the other answer first.

Comment: also, your code is bugged: it prints 4bytes, but only advances 1byte, so the outputs overlap 3bytes, and the last 3 outputs will have the last values 'undefined', and its data.data[...].

Comment: yes dude, it's buggy I admit that.. I had answered it when I'm bit sleepy :) Updated my post. Please have a look at my update. have a Nice Day!

Comment: `(x=function(){})();` it's a self executing anonymous function, which initiates the function. coming to frame rate [*30fps*] , you can atleast the Image Data Details Instead of hanging up your browser. well I won't beg you to accept my answer, 'cause I don't get anything, If my answer is accepted or even downvoted :)  BTW welcome to stackoverflow.com

Comment: it solves the freezing, but i figured that if i dont dump to console the performance is good enough to do all calculations directly without freezing.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a canvas of 1px X 1px, move the image and then read the imageData